# AutoLayout not updating views programmatically - Swift

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout

I have the following code where I'm creating and laying out everything in code. What I'm trying to do is modify the `myTopContainer` when a button is tapped but I can not make the width changed, only the height gets modified.

Any idea why?

```
func setupAutoLayout(){
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        // My Container
        myTopContainer.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: myButton.topAnchor, constant: -5),
        myTopContainer.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50),
        myTopContainer.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor, constant: 15),
        myTopContainer.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor, constant: -15),

        // My Button
        myButton.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 80),
        myButton.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 40),
        myButton.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.trailingAnchor, constant: -15),
        myButton.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.bottomAnchor, constant: -400)
    ])
}


@IBAction func relayoutViews(_ sender: Any) {

    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0, options: .curveEaseIn, animations: {

        self.myTopContainer.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50).isActive = false
        self.myTopContainer.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.leadingAnchor, constant: 15).isActive = false

        // this is working, it changes the height
        self.myTopContainer.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 10).isActive = true
        // this is not doing anything
        self.myTopContainer.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.myButton.trailingAnchor).isActive = true

        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()

    })
}
```

[image]

Comment: Watch the console. You are adding conflicting constraints.

Comment: What @matt said. The only reason the height constraint *appears* to be working is because the layout engine decided to use the new constraint. You should *deactivate* the constraints you want to change along with *activating* the new ones. There are a few ways to accomplish this, but the easiest is to put height/width into two arrays (one for initial, one for resized) and deactivate/activate the appropriate one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A line like this

```
self.myTopContainer.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50).isActive = false
```

Creates a new constraint every time. It doesn't modify the previously created constraint.

When you setupAutolayout you should save a reference to the constraints you want to later modify before actually calling `NSLayoutConstraint.activate()` on them.
Later you can set isActive to false on them.

For example:

```
var someConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint?
func setupAutoLayout(){
    let aConstraint = myTopContainer.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: myButton.topAnchor, constant: -5)
    someConstraint = aConstraint
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        // My Container
        aConstraint
    ])
}

func editConstraint() {
    self.someConstraint?.isActive = false
}
```

Anyway be careful on logs when you edit constraints, it's probable that you could break something while editing. If you see those logs of broken constraint than it means that something is still wrong (even if it visually looks good, it could crash or not work properly in some other situation)

Comment: @ Enricoza -  Ok, if I understand it correctly in order to `activate` or `deactivate` constraints you need to keep track of your constraints by assigning them to a variable, makes sense. Quick question: Can a constraint be re-attached to a different view at a later time if desired? In other words, e.g., can `someConstraint ` be re-attached to a `someOtherView`, something like... `someConstraint = myTopContainer.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: someOtherView.topAnchor, constant: -5)`. It doesn't seem to work, is this even possible?

Comment: If you do that you are going to create a new one, whitout destroying the first one... but it’s possible (but I wouldn’t recommend it). You should have a reference to the ones you want to change (if you want to change for example the constant) or activate/deactivate